# Any idea how to build a more complete raytracer in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, prototype, raytracing

I am currently take a course on production graphics and since we are spend the whole semester building a raytracer I would like to experiment as much as possible. I used to use C++ but it gets really messy at some point. And I trust haskell as a very good language for prototyping, and clean code. However, I would really appreciate some advice as now I could not find a way for data representation.

Here is currently what I thought.

A raytracer in general is a `scene` as an environment so I might use a monad (build upon state monad probably) to connect different part in the tracer.

`Camera` is the simplest. It has Position and Direction and can be moved around and rotate.

The other parts become tricky. I wish to have `Screen` which could either generate pinhole or depth of field, and a list of `lights` that could be `environment`, `point light`, `area light` or `directional light`. The objects in the `scene` is made up by `material` and `geometry` where material might have `phong` or `glossy` or `transparent` so on and so forth, and `geometry` could be `sphere` `triangle` `plane` or a bunch of them (I am thinking `bhv` or `kdtree` as representation)

So, if I am in C++, I am pretty sure I will use inheritance to express such polymorphism. However, I am stuck on how should I represent that in haskell.

My initial attempt (if I do not have to consider secondary ray at all) is to use `typeclass`. So I have something like this

```
class Geometry geo where
    intersect :: geo -> Ray -> Intersection
class Material mat where
    shade :: (Light l) => mat -> Intersection -> l -> Color
```

And so I define my Objects in the following way. I looked up and I tend to use `RankNTypes` (I think I made a mistake here)

```
data Object = forall . geo mat (Geometry geo, Material mat) => Object geo mat
```

Then I found I could not go on if I plan to implement the following function.

```
raytrace_objects :: (Material mat) => Ray -> [Objects] -> (Intersection, mat)
raytrace_objects ray objects =
  foldl reduce (farest_intersection, blackbody) objects
  where
    reduce (Object geo mat) old@(old_inter, _) =
      if new_inter < old_inter
        then (new_inter, mat)
        else old
      where
        new_inter = intersect ray geo
```

And `blackbody` just return black for the shading function

Suddenly I found that it is impossible!!!! `mat` has to match the material type whatever the nearest objects has. And it is not decidable during the static analysis. So, I am stuck. Is there any suggestion how I could surpass the haskell's type system or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If you are going the existential quantification route, then the output has to be existentially quantified as well. This is likely an overly complex representation, all of these "things" which you've described should just be datatypes. As an aside, the type system is there to help, not hinder you, so if you are fighting against it, it's almost certainly the case that you've modeled something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner you should try to avoid language extensions, because they can mislead you to less ideomatic solutions.

In Haskell, you sometimes rely on functions for polymorphism where you would use inheritance in other languages. Consider this simple sketch, which prefers functions over "objects":

```
type Geometry = Ray -> Intersection
type Material = UV -> Color

data Object = Object { objGeometry :: Geometry
                     , objMaterial :: Material
                     }

blackbody :: Material
blackbody uv = RGB 0 0 0

sphere :: Double -> Geometry
sphere radius ray = ...
```

Of course, to get reasonable performance, this would need to be extended with bounding boxes and other optimizations. Still, it shows that you can approach the problem from a completely different side.

### About your implementation

This looks more like a proper type for `Object`:

```
data Object geo mat = Object ...
```

The constraint `(Geometry geo, Material mat) =>`  should instead go on the functions which handle `Object`, and only when they actually need it.

`raytrace_objects` will not work this way, because the `objects` parameter is of type *list* (`[]`). All elements in a list must be of the same type. This type is fixed at compile time. `Object geo mat` is *not* a plain type, because the parameters are not yet known. So there cannot be any actual values of this type. `Object Sphere Wood` might be a suitable type. Thus, `[Object Sphere Wood]` is a list that can only contain wooden spheres.

**Food for thought and search engines:** `Object geo mat` (which is a short notation for `forall geo mat. Object geo mat`) is a *higher-order type* which has *kind* `* -> * -> *` . `[x]` has kind `* -> *` , and `[Int]` has kind `*` .

This is a key difference between algebraic data types with type-classes in contrast to object-oriented programming: The Haskell compiler needs to know *all* types at compile time, whereas OO languages typically only need to know an interface and do not care about the actual runtime type.

Higher-order types and type-classes are more like *templates* in C++.

### Further pointers

You could solve your problem at hand with heterogenous lists (e.g. `HList` from [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList)), which work more like OO lists in the sense that they can accept objects of varying types. Or you try more idiomatic solutions like the one outlined above.

Comment: Thanks for that. Originally I was translating the C++ code to Haskell. And now I finished the code. The performance is far better than I think, but I still cannot reason about it very well. For the suggestion for function over object, I always have a mental model where in C++ callable function is way faster than lambda closure and for me material has actually two functions.

Comment: I really enjoy haskell. So, what is the idiomatic way of writing haskell? I currently really like the language after this raytracing project. It is just so easy to write new features without worry about existing code.  Currently I used a reader monad for all raytracing settings and a random monad below for any function that needs sampling. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: @darwinsenior: As you will probably be using rendering settings and random numbers a lot throughout the renderer, it is probably perfectly fine. In particular since you split out the constant data into reader instead of just putting everything into a single state. You may still try to keep out the monad of all functions that need neither render settings nor random numbers.

Comment: @darwinsenior: I cannot comment too much on the performance of functions. However, the functions of a type-class get stored in something similar to a "vtable" in C++. So in cases where the compiler cannot optimize it away, calls to functions of a type-class may be more expensive due to an additional indirection. Function vs lambda: Remember that in Haskell, all functions are lambdas: "foo x = x+1" is just short-hand for: "foo = \x -> x+1". However, actual closures get allocated on the heap, and may be more expensive, the more variables they capture.